# Redis defaultDatabase Argument Not Working on Adds

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

So I am adding a key to a redis database (using StackExchange.Redis) that has a connection string as follows:

```
server:6379,ssl=false,abortConnect=false,password=*****,defaultDatabase=1
```

The behavior I am seeing is that keys are added to the default database of 0 not what I specify in my connection string, however it appears the default database in the string is where keys are attempted to be retrieved from.  Any thoughts before I go littering my class with explicit database sets?

***EDIT***

To get objects from cache:

```
public object Get(string key, Type t = null)
{
    var cacheStore = Connection.GetDatabase();
    var cachedItem = cacheStore.StringGet(key);
    return !cachedItem.IsNull ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(cachedItem, t) : null;
}
```

To add objects to cache:

```
public void Add(string key, object value, TimeSpan? expiry)
{
    var cacheStore = Connection.GetDatabase();
    var serializedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
    cacheStore.StringSet(key, serializedData, expiry);
}
```

As mentioned if I pass the database id to Connection.GetDatabase() it works without issue, if I rely on the defaultDatabase argument in the connection string items get added to database 0 and it attempts to retrieve from database 1.

Comment: Add some code like how are you adding/retrieving the objects?

Comment: @thepirat000 done!